# How to pass data from a VC to an embedded TableView with a Stepper

Tags: swift, xcode

Im a trying to pass data from a VC (GameCreatingView) to an embedded TableView (PlayersTableView) using the prepare for Segue to change the number of Rows but it don't seem to work.

first file:

```
class GameCreatingViewController: UIViewController {
    var newGame = Game()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        newGame = Game()
        newGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers = 2
        print(newGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers)
        for  i in 1...6 {
            newGame.playerBook?.players[i].number = i

            if i <= 2 {
                newGame.playerBook?.players[i].alive = true
            } else {
                newGame.playerBook?.players[i].alive = false
            }
        }

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPlayers: UILabel!
    @IBAction func changePlayers(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        numberOfPlayers.text = String(Int(sender.value))
        newGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers = Int(sender.value)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: SetNames, sender: Any?)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "StartGame" {
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? PlayersTableViewController else { return }
            guard let newGame = sender as? Game else { return }


            let tableGame = newGame

            destination.currentGame = tableGame
        }

        if segue.identifier == "SetNames" {
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? GameViewController else { return }
            guard let newGame = sender as? Game else { return }

            let gameToPlay = newGame

            destination.currentGame = gameToPlay
        }



    }
```

second file:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        let numberOfRows = currentGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers ?? 3
        return currentGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers ?? 3
        print("Rows\(numberOfRows)")
    }
```

The number of rows don't change so there are always 3 rows.

[my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaMwE.png)

Comment: Is `PlayersTableViewController` an individual view controller or is it in container view in `GameCreatingView`?

Comment: It is the embedded View

Comment: In which method you put this?

Comment: I tried to put performSegue(withIdentifier: SetNames, sender: Any?) in the ButtonAction but it gives me the error Use of unresolved identifier 'SetNames' but it's the identifier of the segue so I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Do you want to update the tableview values, when play button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you embed another view controller in ContainerView the segue is performed when the parent view controller is loaded. You can get the child view controller reference and pass the data like this.

```
@IBAction func changePlayers(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfPlayers.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    newGame.playerBook?.NumberOfPlayers = Int(sender.value)
    if let vc = self.childViewControllers.first(where: { $0 is PlayersTableViewController }) as? PlayersTableViewController {
        vc.currentGame = self.newGame
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    if let vc = self.childViewControllers.first(where: { $0 is GameViewController }) as? GameViewController {
        vc.currentGame = self.newGame
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got the following errors: Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure ;Closure expression is unused ;Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' ;Expected expression ;Use of unresolved identifier 'vc'

Comment: @Leo Check the updated answer. I've updated the tableview when stepper value is changed. Do you want to update the tableview when play button is tapped?

Comment: I had to change childViewControllers to children to avoid errors but it don't work. There are no errors but there are always 3 rows. No the play button is there to switch to the next view